# How to get the temperature out of Joule heating equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, electric-current, thermal-conductivity

The Joule heating law is defined as Voltage U times current I

$P = U \cdot I$

Out of this you get the energy by multiplying it with the time

$Q_e = P \cdot t$

and consequently you get the temperature of the component by dividing it with the specific heat capacity and mass

$ \theta = \frac{Q_e}{c\cdot m}$

The question is, if you use the above equation with unlimited time, the component will heat itself up to infinite temperature. So, when is the time where the heating of a  certain component stops and the heat transfer to the environment starts.

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you please provide a diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are always exchanging heat with their environment. When two objects, let's call them A and B, are at the same temperature, then the rate of heat flow from A to B equals that from B to A. This is the concept of dynamic equilibrium. If A starts to get hotter than B, then amount of heat flowing from A to B will become greater than that from B to A. There's no discrete time at which this happens; the rates just scale continuously with the temperatures of the objects.

So in your case, the heated object will immediately start giving off more heat to its cooler environment. To simplify problems, it's helpful to imagine scenarios in which we can roughly neglect heat exchange with the environment; maybe we surround the object with something reflective to bounce the emitted heat back, or we heat it so quickly that there's very little time for it to lose much energy. But in reality there is always some net flow of energy from hot to cold, and this will prevent an object from heating up to infinite temperature.

Comment: Normally, an object has a certain heat store capacity and therefore it gets hot. My thoughts were that there must be a limit of energy storage within the object and by exceeding this limit, energy in form of temperature will leave the object to its environment. Or is there any mistake in this thoughts because if the heat transfer starts immediately, like you said, how would it get hot ? Is it just the net flow, so the energy in the object converted to temperature which is bigger than the energy leaving the object or is the ability to store a certain amount of energy ?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Yeah I never realized this, but heat capacity is a misleading term! No heat capacity is directly related to temperature via $T = Q/C$ (assuming that the heat capacity $C$ is constant as a function of temperature, which is often the case). So as you can see from this expression, $T$ increases as soon as $Q$ increases. This makes sense when you think about temperature microscopically; adding heat makes the atoms in a material move faster, which corresponds to a higher temperature. The only limit to heat storage is when something gets so hot that it melts or boils.

Comment: So that's how temperature changes as you add heat. And then as I explain in the above answer, heat flows from hot to cold based on the heat conductivity between two objects. The net rate of heat flow is proportional to the temperature difference between the objects.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, if you use the above equation with unlimited time, the component will heat itself up to infinite temperature. So, when is the time where the heating of a certain component stops and the heat transfer to the environment starts.

The component will heat itself up to infinite temperature iff it's adiabatically insulated and no radiation is escaping the system.
But since you are assuming it to be transferring heat to the environment, it's not adiabatically insulated.
To answer your question, the heating of component never stops and heat transfer begins whenever the equilibrium is disturbed i.e. temperature of component becomes greater than the environment,

The maximum temperature it will attain can be calculated from the Newton's law of cooling which says
$$dQ/dt \propto \Delta T$$
Assuming the environment to be of infinite heat capacity.

So to find temperature you can use
$$P=dQ/dt= \alpha \Delta T$$
So you will get the temperature element will attain at infinite time provided you know the temperature of environment.

There are different methods by which the element will loose it's heat to environment namely radiation (Planck's law), convection and if environment is conducting then with conduction (wires).

Comment: I have not defined usual symbols, but they have their usual meaning.